# Finding gradient using vector identities

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, solution-verification

I am trying to find the solution to :

$$\underline\nabla(\underline m\cdot\underline rr^{-3})$$

Where $\underline m$ is a constant vector, $\underline r$ is the position vector and r is the magnitude of the position vector

### EDIT :For now I have$$=(\underline m\cdot\underline\nabla)\underline rr^{-3}=r^{-3}(\underline m\cdot\underline\nabla)\underline r + \underline r(\underline m\cdot\underline\nabla)r^{-3}=(r^2\underline m -3\underline r(\underline m \cdot \underline r))r^{-5}$$

Is this correct ? The answer is was told I should get was $((r^2\cdot\underline m) -3\underline r(\underline m \cdot \underline r))r^{-5}$ . I don't know if my working is wrong or the expected answer. Am I missing something? What is it ? Does $(r^2\underline m)=(r^2\cdot\underline m)$?

I am quite rusty with my vec identities. Can someone please show me a worked solution ? Just a solution to begin with would also be nice. Pls help. Thanks

Comment: @MatthewHolder I dont quite understand what you mean. Im looking for a solution to the gradient of the dot product I wrote above

Comment: Oh my bad. Sorry, I didn't catch the the word "vector" before the word "constant". Just a quick question. If $r$ is a position *vector*, what is $r^{-3}$ supposed to represent?

Comment: @MatthewHolder $r^{-3}$ is the magnitude of the position vector to the -3 power

Comment: Okay then you should be writing $||r||^{-3}$ instead of $r^{-3}$ because you cannot raise vectors to powers.

Comment: @MatthewHolder sorry, normally the notation r is used for magnitude of $\underline r$. I have updated the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\rho$ represent the distance from the origin
$$\eqalign{
\rho^2 &= r\cdot r \quad\implies\quad \rho\,d\rho &= r\cdot dr \\
}$$
Use this to calculate the differential and the gradient of the proposed function.
$$\eqalign{
 \lambda &= \rho^{-3}(m\cdot r) \\
d\lambda
 &= \rho^{-3}(m\cdot dr) -(3\rho^{-4}d\rho)\,(m\cdot r) \\
 &= \rho^{-3}m\cdot dr -3\lambda\rho^{-2}\,\rho\,d\rho \\
 &= \rho^{-3}m\cdot dr -3\lambda\rho^{-2}\,r\cdot dr \\
 &= (\rho^{-3}m -3\lambda\rho^{-2}r)\cdot dr \\
\nabla\lambda
 &= \rho^{-3}m -3\lambda\rho^{-2}r \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks ! But I am trying to find the solution using vector identities

Comment: So the solution you got is the same as the one I got? meaning the solution I was told I am supposed to get is wrong ?

Comment: The problem with the supposed solution is that $r^2$ is not a vector, so $(r^2\cdot m)$ makes no sense.

Comment: I don't know what to think about it, thats the answer my professor gave and I was questioning it.

Comment: I tried to achieve an answer by doing all of the operations physically by defining the position vector as $xe_1+ye_2+ze_3$
, the m vector as $m_xe_1+m_ye_2+m_ze_3$ and using the definition of the grad operator to manually compute it. I got the answer with the $(r^{2}\cdot \underline m)$

Comment: If you can also do it manually and tell me the result you get I will highly appreciate it !